# python 2.7 : Tkinter ERROR: can't find package tile

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk, rhel5

I created GUI in Python (Python2.7) using Tkinter. I wish to have it up and running for both RHEL7.4 and RHEL5.11 versions. On REHL7.4, it works fine but on RHEL5.11, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure_workstation.py", line 28, in <module>
    app = ConfigureWorkstation(wsObj)
  File "/tmp/hnoman/v0.62/ConfigureWorkstation.py", line 90, in __init__
    frame = F(self.fMenu, self)
  File "/tmp/hnoman/v0.62/WorkstationInfoMenu.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.generateHostnameFrame()
  File "/tmp/hnoman/v0.62/WorkstationInfoMenu.py", line 50, in generateHostnameFrame
    self.oLocation = ttk.OptionMenu(self.fHostname, self.location, dict[1], *dict.values())
  File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/ttk.py", line 1591, in __init__
    Menubutton.__init__(self, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/ttk.py", line 797, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::menubutton", kw)
  File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/ttk.py", line 554, in __init__
    _load_tile(master)
  File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/ttk.py", line 46, in _load_tile
    master.tk.eval('package require tile') # TclError may be raised here
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tile
```

Can someone guide how to overcome this?

Comment: RHEL 5.11 is out of extended life cycle support.

Comment: I am aware of that. But i was wondering if there is still a workaround for that

Comment: Do a custom install of Python which isn't broken? This is all dealing with stuff out of support, and it's referring to a package on the Tcl side that isn't usually there either. There's too many layers of problems for me to want to try to dig through them all.